# reinforcement learning - how to use a q learning algorithm for a reinforce.jl environment?

Tags: julia, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've created this MDP environment using reinforce.jl. It's supposed to mimic the cake eating problem, or consumption-savings problem. I wanna use a q learning algorithm  to find the optimal policy. However, reinforce.jl package only has sarsa policy (correct me if I'm wrong). I put the error message at the bottom of my code for when I try to implement a q learning algorithm. I get a method error but don't know if there is a way to fix this.

```
using Reinforce
import Reinforce.step!
import Reinforce.reset!
using Reinforce: AbstractEnvironment
import Reinforce: reset!, actions, finished, step!

mutable struct Savings<: AbstractEnvironment
  state::Float64
  reward::Float64
  steps::Int
  maxsteps::Int
end

Savings(maxsteps = 2) = Savings(10.0, 0.0, 0.0,maxsteps)

function reset!(env::Savings)
  env.state = 10.0
  env.reward = 0.0
  env.steps = 0
  env
end


A = Reinforce.actions(env::Savings, s) =  (1.0,2.0,3.0)
finished(env::Savings, s′) = env.state == 0
#step function

function step!(env::Savings, s::Float64, a::Float64)
    wealth = env.state
    if a < wealth
        newwealth = (wealth - a)*1.25
        env.reward =  a
    else
        env.reward = -a
        newwealth = 0
    end
    env.state = newwealth
    return env.reward, env.state

end

env = Savings()

#reinforce sarsa 
function episode!(env, π = RandomPolicy())
  ep = Episode(env, π)
  for (s, a, r, s′) in ep
  end
  ep.total_reward, ep.niter
end

mutable struct SavingsPolicy <: Reinforce.AbstractPolicy end
Reinforce.action(policy::SavingsPolicy, r, s, A) = rand(A)

R, n = episode!(env, SavingsPolicy())
println("reward: $R, iter: $n")
#
#an example of a q learning package that I awnna use
using QMDP
#] initialize POMDP

# initialize the solver
# key-word args are the maximum number of iterations the solver will run for, and the Bellman tolerance
solver = QMDPSolver(max_iterations=20,
                    belres=1e-3,
                    verbose=true
                   )

# run the solver
policy = solve(solver, env)
```

Error message:

```
MethodError: no method matching solve(::QMDPSolver{DiscreteValueIteration.ValueIterationSolver}, ::Savings)
Closest candidates are:
  solve(::QMDPSolver, !Matched::POMDPs.POMDP) at C:\Users\danor\.julia\packages\QMDP\bYyCH\src\vanilla.jl:33
top-level scope at reinforce.jl:76
include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at loading.jl:1088
```

Comment: And again, the error message tells you quite precisely what the issue is: you called `solve` on `solver` and something of type `savings`, whereas the second argument needs to have type `POMDP`.

Comment: Now, since you have a lot of small questions, I'd rather recommend asking them on the [Julia Slack](https://julialang.org/slack/), [Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/), or [Zulip](https://julialang.zulipchat.com/). There's loads of really helpful people there, and you might resolve small issue quicker. Your way of iteratively asking and immediately deleting questions is not the best way to use StackOverflow.